# -f unknown option bash

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to write a short function that will go to a specific folder from the home directory and then find any files that have been accessed in the past few days.

```
function restore5 {
    cd /Volumes/FTP/RESTORES
    find . type -f -atime +5 | less
}
```

When I run this function I receive an error that says: find: -f: unknown option.
I don't get this error code when I type the commands manually so I am curious to find out what have I missed?

Also if I wanted to expand upon this and add to the end of the function an if unsuccessful type command, would "| |" be the more appropriate command to use? My thoughts were along the lines of:

```
| | echo "No files found"
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to pipe find to wc -l and do a numeric test on the result to display the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `find . -type f -atime +5 | less`

Answer (score 0):

should you not be using

```
find . - type f -atime +5 | less
```

Extract from man page of find:

```
  -type c
          File is of type c:

          b      block (buffered) special

          c      character (unbuffered) special

          d      directory

          p      named pipe (FIFO)

          f      regular file

          l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the -follow option is in effect, unless the symbolic link is broken.  If you
                 want to search for symbolic links when -L is in effect, use -xtype.

          s      socket

          D      door (Solaris)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the manual for find the syntax for the type command is **-type f** try using that instead of your **. type -f**.

Not sure if you are doing something with the **. type** that I can't understand, But hope it helps.